# How to iterate an XML field in SQL Server using the value() function

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have the following XML field():

```
<A>
  <B name="B1">
    <C>
      <D name="D1">
        <E name="E1"/>
        <E name="E2"/>
        <E name="E3"/>
      </D>
      <D name="D2">
        <E name="E4"/>
        <E name="E5"/>
        <E name="E6"/>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
  <B name="B3">
    <C>
      <D name="D11">
        <E name="E11"/>
        <E name="E22"/>
        <E name="E33"/>
      </D>
      <D name="D22">
        <E name="E44"/>
        <E name="E55"/>
        <E name="E66"/>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

If I want to use `nodes()` and `value()` to get the data from XML, what should I do, the result should be like:

| B | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | D1 | E1 |
| B1 | D1 | E2 |
| B1 | D1 | E3 |
| B2 | D2 | E4 |
| .. |  |  |
| B3 | D22 | E66 |

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT NodePath.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') B,
    NodePath.value('(./C/D/@name)[1]', 'varchar(64)') D,
    NodePath.value('(./C/D/E/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') E
FROM XmlTable xt
cross apply xt.XmlField.nodes('/A/B') Node(NodePath)
```

but I seems like that it only takes one E from different B

Comment: The example XML is not valid. Closing tags should use the `/` character, not the "\" character. e.g.: `<D>...</D>`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, sry, I have corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NodePath.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') B,
    --NodePath.value('(./C/D/@name)[1]', 'varchar(64)') D,
    --NodePath.value('(./C/D/E/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') E,
    d.d.value('@name', 'varchar(64)') AS D,
    e.e.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') AS E
FROM XmlTable xt
CROSS APPLY xt.XmlField.nodes('/A/B') AS Node(NodePath)
CROSS APPLY Node.NodePath.nodes('C/D') AS d(d)
CROSS APPLY d.d.nodes('E') AS e(e)
```

Comment: Thank you, It works! And I am also wondering its performance. Will its performance better than the following query?  ```SELECT NodePath.value(../../../'@name', 'varchar(100)') B,
    NodePath.value('@../name', 'varchar(64)') AS D,
    NodePath.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') AS E
FROM XmlTable xt
CROSS APPLY xt.XmlField.nodes('/A/B/C/D/E') AS Node(NodePath)```

Comment: ..@zening.chen .In general,navigating up the xml structure/hierarchy(from a child to parent node) using parent:: or the '../' abbreviation is more expensive/costly than retrieving the parent first and then the children.You could compare&check the differences of the two execution plans(going up the hierarchy requires 2 additional xpath filters). This does not mean that your suggestion will be slower. A more expensive query gets more memory granted and sometimes this could make the expensive query run faster than a cheaper one.Just test it with your environment and pick the one that suits you.